# Is there a way to get script name while executing it with LPrun of LinQPad?

Tags: c#, linqpad

If I have a script named `some_script.linq`

```
void Main()
{
  string scriptName = SomeHowGetTheNameOfThisScript(); //I want this function
  Console.WriteLine(scriptName);
}
```

I want the `"some_script.linq"` to be displayed when I run `lprun -lang=program some_script.linq`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `LINQPad.Util.CurrentQueryPath`.

```
void Main()
{
    string scriptName = Path.GetFileName(Util.CurrentQueryPath);
    Console.WriteLine(scriptName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer myself: `Environment.CommandLine` with some parsing do the work